# How to add a link to a word?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to add a link into "here" using C# webform.aspx.cs page , so  doesn't work.

EG. "The password has expired. Please click here to reset your password."

I'll able to click on "here" then will redirect.

```
errMsg.InnerText= "The password has expired. Please click here to reset your 
password.";
```

Comment: This question needs more description.  I assume you're using WPF or Windows Forms.  If the former https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.hyperlink(v=vs.110).aspx, If the latter, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.linklabel.aspx.  I think in either case, google could have figured this one out for you.

Comment: InnerText allows text, not hypertext or any other markup. (Please add tags such as [asp.net]).

Answer (score 0):

```
errMsg.InnerHtml= "The password has expired. Please click <a href='$your url$' >here</a> to reset your password.";
```

in place of `$your url$` enter url of reset password page.